# how the concurrent task execution?

Tags: operating-system

I am the newer to OS so have some problems about concurrent tasks problem as the following.
2 concurrent tasks, in which each assignment statement execute atomically. And the shared variable x and y are set to 0.

```
Task 0 :  x = 1 a = y   Task 1 :  y = 1  b = x
```

At the end of the concurrent tasks,what must be the value of a and b?

```
A.(a == 0) -> (b == 1)
B.(b == 0) -> (a == 1)
C.(a == 0) -> (b == 1)
D none
```

Any one could explain this for me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If the assignments are truly atomic they cannot be executed concurrently. The output will depend on the exact order in which the statements are executed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 4 different (atomic) operations and no guarantee on the order of operations in different tasks (in some cases even the order of operations in the same thread can be interchanged, but let's ignore this for now), we can have the following possible outcomes if the first operation executed is T0_1 (1st op of task 0):

```
       T0_1
T0_2          T1_1
T1_1      T0_2    T1_2
T1_2      T1_2    T0_2
```

So 3 possible paths, and the same amount if the execution starts with T1_1, so in total 6 possible outcomes, but as I mentioned this is only in case the order of operations in the same task is not changed.